# dchpcd[PID]: eth0: {IPV6} is unreachable, expiring it

Tags: python, ethernet, ipv6

I have a small python script that uses Requests and simply does a GET request from an api to pull data.  This script works fine on my computer and fine on a pi A, but not on the actual Pi B that I'm trying use it with.

Basically the script fails to execute the GET request on some URLS, not all, just some....using `tail -f /var/log/syslog` I can see that this keeps happening:

```
Feb 22 17:57:55 raspberrypi dhcpcd[445]: eth0: fe80::3e7a:8aff:fe59:68d6 is unreachable, expiring it
Feb 22 17:58:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[445]: eth0: fe80::3e7a:8aff:fe59:68d6 is unreachable, expiring it
Feb 22 17:58:44 raspberrypi dhcpcd[445]: eth0: fe80::3e7a:8aff:fe59:68d6 is unreachable, expiring it
Feb 22 17:59:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[445]: eth0: fe80::3e7a:8aff:fe59:68d6 is unreachable, expiring it
Feb 22 17:59:16 raspberrypi dhcpcd[445]: eth0: fe80::3e7a:8aff:fe59:68d6 is unreachable, expiring it
Feb 22 17:59:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[445]: eth0: fe80::3e7a:8aff:fe59:68d6 is unreachable, expiring it
Feb 22 18:33:12 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 17' suspended, next retry is Mon Feb 22 18:34:42 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

my `ifconfig` settings:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb  
          inet addr:10.0.0.21  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: bbbb::bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: bbbb:bbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb/64     Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13803 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2410136 (2.2 MiB)  TX bytes:4368966 (4.1 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6156 (6.0 KiB)  TX bytes:6156 (6.0 KiB)
```

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

I took off real mac address and ipv6 addresses (yes the 2nd eth0 IPV6address looks malformed, but that's what it looked like on my settings)

Also, its not that nothing works - its that certain GET requests don't work...any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `dhcpcd`, which is the default for newer Raspbian, setting static like this doesn't work. (Actually it may, but this won't shop `dhcpcd` from trying to allocate too). See  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697 for a tutorial.

Are you actually trying to use `ipv6`?

PS There is no need to be coy about the link-local address. This is not routable. Mine is `inet6 addr: fe80::3e93:18ca:78ee:7e46/64 Scope:Link`

Comment: I COMPLETELY forgot about this question - turns out the issue was related to an issue related to my client's ISP.